# Problema para implentar paypal

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Pues intento implementar el código para hacer el pago y me da el error

> sizeof(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable|array, string
> given

Lo peor es que no tengo ningún `sizeof()` ni nada en todo el código. Voy a pasar el controlador a ver si alguien tiene idea.

Estoy usando la libreria
rest-api-sdk-php

Estoy usando **laravel**.

```
 // Configura el pago
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');

        $payer = new Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);

        $amount = new Amount();


        $precio = (float) $request->input('precio');
        //dd($amount);
        $amount->setTotal(floatval($request->input('precio')));



        $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
        $transaction = new Transaction([
            'amount' => [
                'total' => $precio,
                'currency' => 'EUR',
            ],
        ]);


        $payment->setTransactions([$transaction]);

        // Configura las URL de redirección después del pago
        $redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(route('payment.success'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(route('payment.cancel'));
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);


 try {
            $payment->create($apiContext);
            // Redirige al usuario a la URL de aprobación de PayPal
            return redirect($payment->getApprovalLink());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Muestra información detallada sobre la excepción en los logs
            Log::error('Error al crear el pago en PayPal', ['exception' => $e]);

            // Redirige a una página de error
            return redirect()->route('payment.error');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Cuando te dice el error, también te dirá en qué línea de qué archivo se produce, y a partir de ahí puedes tirar del hilo y depurar. El `sizeof()` estárá en la librería que usas, pero cuando tires del hilo posiblemente verás que en algún momento pasas a alguna función o método un parámetro que es string en vez de array.

Comment: El problema me lo da aqui  

 $payment->create($apiContext);

Y es por eso que no entiendo el porque porque el dato que le paso es decimal luego he mirado el dd($amount) para ver dato pasa y es correcto que seria esto



`
PayPal\Api\Amount {#391 ▼ // app/Http/Controllers/PaypalController.php:70
  -_propMap: array:2 [▼
    "currency" => "EUR"
    "total" => "40.00"
  ]
}
`

Comment: No veo dónde inicializas `$apiContext`. En cualquier caso, tienes que depurar ayudándote del log de errores.